# How to place Javascript in SVG html box

Tags: javascript, html

Hi all I have the following code and I would like to place the javascript button inside the SVG box. I think I am not understanding how to pass the coordinated in order to place it inside. I am trying the following code but is not working

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
</head>
    <body>

        <div style="max-width:1000px;">

            <div class="scaling-svg-container" style="padding-bottom: 100%; max-width: 1000px; margin: 0px auto 0px auto; ">

                <svg id="ProvaJJ" class="scaling-svg" style="max-width: 1000px;" id="graphic" xmlns="https://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="https://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 750 750" enable-background="new 0 0 750 750" xml:space="preserve">
                    <g id="background">
                        <rect fill="#C1D3E9" width="750" height="750"/>
                    <g> id="inputBackground">
                        <script>
                        function confirmAction() {
                             let confirmAction = confirm("Are you sure to execute this action?");
                              if (confirmAction) {
                                           alert("Action successfully executed");
                               } else {
                                 alert("Action canceled");
                                  }
                              }
                        </script>
                        <!--<script>
                            alert( 'Hello, world!' );
                        </script> -->
                        <!--<polygon fill="#FFFFFF" points="114.089,97.5 114.089,180 353.064,204 592.039,180 592.039,97.5   "/> -->
                        <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 59.138 53.6896)" fill="#333333" font-family="'InterFace-Regular'" font-size="24px"> Alessia is a 25 years old, blond and outstanding PhD student
                            </tspan><tspan x="0" y="44.4" fill="#333333" font-family="'InterFace-Regular'" font-size="24px">She has a master degree in something.
                        </tspan></tspan><tspan x="0" y="94.4" fill="#333333" font-family="'InterFace-Regular'" font-size="24px">something .</tspan></text>

                        <script type = Javascript>
                            <ul id = "messages"></ul>
                            <input id = "textbox" type ="text">
                            <button id ="btn">click</button>
                        </script>

                </svg>

            </div>

        </div>
s
        <!--<script src="prova.js"></script>-->

    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues:

1- `type = Javascript` you need to add the property with double qoutetion or remove the type attribute. so you can use `<script>` or `<script type="javascript"`

2- don't write the html between script tags.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
</head>
    <body>

        <div style="max-width:1000px;">

            <div class="scaling-svg-container" style="padding-bottom: 100%; max-width: 1000px; margin: 0px auto 0px auto; ">

                <svg id="ProvaJJ" class="scaling-svg" style="max-width: 1000px;" id="graphic" xmlns="https://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="https://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 750 750" enable-background="new 0 0 750 750" xml:space="preserve">
                    <g id="background">
                        <rect fill="#C1D3E9" width="750" height="750"/>
                    <g> id="inputBackground">
                        <script>
                        function confirmAction() {
                             let confirmAction = confirm("Are you sure to execute this action?");
                              if (confirmAction) {
                                           alert("Action successfully executed");
                               } else {
                                 alert("Action canceled");
                                  }
                              }
                        </script>
                        <!--<script>
                            alert( 'Hello, world!' );
                        </script> -->
                        <!--<polygon fill="#FFFFFF" points="114.089,97.5 114.089,180 353.064,204 592.039,180 592.039,97.5   "/> -->
                        <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 59.138 53.6896)" fill="#333333" font-family="'InterFace-Regular'" font-size="24px"> Alessia is a 25 years old, blond and outstanding PhD student
                            </tspan><tspan x="0" y="44.4" fill="#333333" font-family="'InterFace-Regular'" font-size="24px">She has a master degree in something.
                        </tspan></tspan><tspan x="0" y="94.4" fill="#333333" font-family="'InterFace-Regular'" font-size="24px">something .</tspan></text>

 <a xlink:href="#" id="btn"><polygon fill="none" points="162,263.3 251.6,256 252.7,273.3 163,280.5"/><text id="messages" x="0" y="184.4" fill="#333333" font-family="'TradeGothicLT-Bold'" font-size="12.9937">Click</text></a>

                  
                        <script>
                              
                                document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
                                  e.preventDefault()
                                  document.getElementById('messages').textContent = "clicked"
                                })
                                
                           
                        
                        </script>

                </svg>

            </div>

        </div>
        <!--<script src="prova.js"></script>-->

    </body>

</html>
```